# Using the $ selector in Chrome Console with on jQuery

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm wondering why I can use `$('.myelement')` in Google Chrome console? I thought that was only a jQuery thing.

Is this part of JavaScript?

Comment: No, probably Chrome added to its console, but it isn't pure JS.

Answer (score 2):

The [$ function is provided by the Chrome Dev Tools API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#queryselector) although it will be overwritten if the page provides a global `$` variable (e.g. by loading jQuery).

It is not part of JavaScript (nor are any DOM manipulation functions).